# ForEach Only Performing Task Once

Tags: php, arrays, twitter, foreach

I have an array that is a json_decode of some data retrieved from the twitter API.
Here is the section of the array than I'm using:

```
Array(
    [0]=>stdClass Object (
        [user] => stdClass Object (
            [screen_name] => User1
        )
        [text] => Text of message
        [id] => 220301332135952385
        [created_at] => Tue Jul 03 23:41:45 +0000 2012
    )

    [1]=>stdClass Object (
        [user] => stdClass Object (
            [screen_name] => User2
        )
        [text] => Text of message
        [id] => 220301332135952385
        [created_at] => Tue Jul 03 23:41:45 +0000 2012
    )
)
```

The problem I'm running into is that my PHP is only getting the values `User1` and `Text of message` from it. My actual array is much longer, but it follows the above pattern.
Here is my PHP:

```
foreach($tweet as $num => $val) {
  $username = $tweet[$num]->user->screen_name;
  echo $num . "-USER-" . $username . "-NAME ";
  $tweet = $tweet[$num]->text;
  $id = $tweet[$num]->id_str;
  $year = substr($tweet[$num]->created_at, -4);

  $statement = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO table (username, tweet, id, year) VALUES ('$username', '$tweet', '$id', '$year')");
  $statement->execute();
}
```

`$tweet` is my array. The `echo` in there is something I was using for debugging. It outputs:

```
1-USER-User1-NAME 2-USER--NAME 3-USER--NAME
```

I'm expecting:

```
1-USER-User1-NAME 2-USER-User2-NAME
```

Lastly, my database only receives `User1` in the username column and `Text of message` in the tweet column. Nothing gets inserted into id or year. Although, it does create empty rows for each tweet after the first. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try debugging , delete all what is in your foreach loop,and test a print_r($tweet)

Comment: @FaceOfJock That foreach is inside another foreach. I have a print_r inside of the first foreach.

Comment: I said this because your $tweet's size is 3 and you showed your array with 2 objects only so may be you have something wrong inside your 2nd foreach,try to add another print_r and show me result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already resolved this problem, here is what's happening:

At the third line in your `foreach` loop you are replacing the value of `$tweet` which is the reason why you only see the first User's `username` and `tweet` in the database.  The reason you don't get 'id' and 'year' is because after `tweet` has now become `$tweet[$num]->text` which is a string.

Another problem is in your `$id = $tweet[$num]->id_str`.  This isn't working anyway because of the above reason but once you fix the above problem your `$id` would still be null.

Try the following:

```
foreach($tweet as $num => $val) {
  $username = $tweet[$num]->user->screen_name;
  echo $num . "-USER-" . $username . "-NAME ";
  $user_tweet = $tweet[$num]->text; // Use $user_tweet = ... instead of $tweet = ...
  $id = $tweet[$num]->id; // Replace $id_str with $id
  $year = substr($tweet[$num]->created_at, -4);

  $statement = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO table (username, tweet, id, year) VALUES ('$username', '$user_tweet', '$id', '$year')");
  $statement->execute();
}
```

I'm not sure why you chose to use `$tweet[$num]` instead of `$val`.

Also to utilize prepared statements to it's fullest in your code, suggest using prepared parameterized query as follows (and here is why "[SQL Injection Prevention-Defense Option 1: Parameterized Queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1%3a_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29)"):

```
$statement = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO table (username, tweet, id, year) VALUES (:username, :user_tweet, :id, :year)");
$statement->bindParam(':username', $username);
$statement->bindParam(':user_tweet', $user_tweet);
$statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
$statement->bindParam(':year', $year);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Didn't catch that I was using $tweet as a variable twice.
Thanks a ton!